# Selective frame-busting Javascript

Tags: javascript, frames

At some point last month, a random website decided to serve my company's website in a frame. Ignoring the question of "what are they doing?" for a minute, I used some simple frame-buster Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href ;
}
</script>
```

That part works great. The problem is, not all frames are bad: if someone comes to the site via [ow.ly](http://ow.ly/), we don't want to destroy their frame. I've tried a few things, either to whitelist [ow.ly](http://ow.ly/) or to blacklist the offending website, but I can't get around the cross-frame security long enough to search `top.location`. Is there anything I can only block some frames, based on the URL?

To clarify, I realize that I'm unlikely to win the frame-busting arms race. I'm fine with that. What I'm trying to do is establish a whitelist of sites that are allowed to show our site in a frame.

Comment: Do you have to do it in javascript?. With what programming language are working on server (asp, asp.net, php)?

Comment: Does the server platform matter? Anything IIS can do over HTTP, Tomcat can do. The server in question is on IIS/ASP.NET/C# right now, but it might not stay there long-term.

Comment: ok, I had the same problem and maybe you could help with the solutions we find in the language we use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employ some help from your back-end. You could check the HTTP referrer header and then enable your frame-buster accordingly.

Comment: +1: This is the best option I've seen, assuming you genuinely can't get that information on the client side. I'll wait to accept for a day or two, in case there's a way.

Comment: Frame-buster vs frame-buster-buster war is a horrific waste of time. Find something to do that will actually have a positive impact on your user base.